# Footer Won't Stretch Across Full Page

Tags: html, css, footer

So I've been trying to get my footer to stretch across the page, but for whatever reason it's only matching the width of my body. The footer isn't within the body, I have tried to make 100% width with no results, tried 110% but it wanders off to the right, tried to shift the margin or position with no luck either, margin 0, padding 0, pretty much everything I could think of or find with no luck. This is what I ended with tonight code wise.

HTML

```
</body>
 <footer>    
  <?php include ('common/footer_links.php');?> 
 </footer>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    font: 14px/18px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000;
    background-image: url(../images/backgroundtile.png);
    width: 1140px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

footer{
    clear: both;
    height: 100px;
    background: #333;
    float: none !important;
}
```

Comment: You have to add <footer> inside <body>

Comment: It is strange !! why you have used width to body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    font: 14px/18px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000;
    background-image: url(../images/backgroundtile.png);
    width: 1140px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

footer{
    clear: both;
    height: 100px;
    background: #333;
    float: none !important;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="body"></div>
    <footer>    
      <?php include ('common/footer_links.php');?> 
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The footer cannot be outside the body, if you do so it will be an invalid HTML page. in fact all the contents of a page should be inside the body tag.

```
<html>
<body> 
 <footer>    
  <?php include ('common/footer_links.php');?> 
 </footer>   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

True structure)

```
<html>
  <body>
    <section class="content"></section>
    <footer></footer>
  </body>
</html>
```